# how to store multiple HTTP request query parameter in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring

Expose an API to provide request IDs in  query parameters.
On receival of IDs that particular id is stored by  first microservice and will be processed further by another microservice.
The complete task is performed by two microservices.
First microservice will capture the Issue Id and store it.
Second Microservice will count the number of Issue IDs received by First Microservices.

Then it will access each Issue ID from the first Microservice one by one.
A scheduler will be configured which will run every 5 mins to check the number of stored Issue Ids for processing then it will dump them one by one into the database.

My question is how to store multiple HTTP request query parameters and transfer them to another microservice one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a classic place to use a queue. If you expect very few ids - you could try an in-memory queue - where you simply keep adding these issue ids to the queue. You can have an API in microservice #1 that fetches the current queue size which can be polled (through the cron) by microservice #2.

The con of the above approach is that your data will be lost in case of an app crash/shutdown/redeployment. To make this more sturdy, you can employ a different kind of queue - SQS looks like a good fit.

You may even use a cache store for this - but again that suffers from the same data volatility issue.

In fact, if this is the only function of microservice #1 - have a queue instead. For a self managed one, you'll have to solve for data redundancy. A managed one will take care of that detail for you.

Comment: Didn't expect such quick answer .Thanks Bro!